# Typescript GET object with date type

Tags: json, angular, rest, http, typescript

I have python REST API and angular2 on frontend. Now I need to parse GET request to objects Answer with date type field. Example of my json:

```
{
"date_answer": "2015/07/05", 
"id": 1, 
"text": "some text",
```

}

I use this code in controller:

```
getAnswers() : Observable<Answer[]> {
return this.http.get(this.answerUrl)
          .map((res:Response) => res.json())
          .catch((error:any) => Observable.throw(error.json().error || 'Server error'));}
```

What I am trying to do is to solve my problem with parsing Date field in constructor like this:

```
 export class Answer {
  id: number;
  text: string;
  date_answer: Date;

  constructor(
    id: number, 
    text: string, 
    date_string: string
    ){
      this.date_answer = new Date(date_string)
    }
}
```

But this approach does't help. Maybe there are some better way to get date from json as Date type.

Comment: is the date always in the same format **yyyy/mm/dd** ?

Comment: @codtex I have only two elements in json for test. And they both have same format yyyy/mm/dd.

Comment: A simple way could be `new Date(Date.parse('2015/07/05'))` will return something like `2015-07-04T21:00:00.000Z` depending on the time zone you are. Another not very nice solution would be to split and parse the date the dirty way :)

Comment: Why doesn't the above approach work ?

Comment: Are you asking about Date type"?

Answer (score 0):

I'm using [class-transformer](https://github.com/pleerock/class-transformer) by pleerock to achieve parsing.

Maybe you take a look at it.